# Class that provides thread-safe access to data of different types (Proposal, Code review)

Tags: c++, struct, concurrency, raspberry-pi, thread-safety

Still on a beginner level, I am currently writing a **multithreaded application for raspi 4 in C++** that performs a bunch of operations on frames coming from a time-of-flight depth camera.

## Situation

My threads, as well as callbacks from the depth-camera-library, produce various kinds of data (ranging from bools to more complex types like opencv mats, etc.). I want **to collect some relevant data at a single place** and then send it  to a smartphone monitoring-app from time to time and via UDP, allowing me to monitor the behaviour of the threads...

I have no control over when a thread accesses parts of the data nor can I guarantee, that they aren't accessing it concurrently. I, therefore, searched for a way that enables me to write and read data into a struct without having to worry about thread-safeness at all. But I couldn't find a good solution for my needs so far.

***"Don't use globals"*** 
*I know that this is a global-like concept and that it should be avoided, if possible. As this is some kind of logging/monitoring, I would consider it as a cross-cutting-concern and manage it this way...*

## Code / Proposal

So I came up with this one, which I would be very happy to see reviewed by a concurrency expert:

*You can also run the code [here online!](http://www.cpp.sh/2kghx)*

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

// Class that provides a thread-safe / protected data struct -> "ProtData"
class ProtData {
 private:
  // Struct to store data.
  // Core concern: How can I access this in a thread-safe manner?
  struct Data {
    int testInt;
    bool testBool;
    // OpenCV::Mat (CV_8UC1)
    // ... and a lot more types
  };
  Data _data;         // Here my data gets stored
  std::mutex _mutex;  // private mutex to achieve protection

  // As long it is in scope this protecting wrapper keeps the mutex locked
  // and provides a public way to access the data structure
  class ProtectingWrapper {
   public:
    ProtectingWrapper(Data& data, std::mutex& mutex)
        : data(data), _lock(mutex) {}
    Data& data;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock;
  };

 public:
  // public function to return an instance of this protecting wrapper
  ProtectingWrapper getAccess();
};

// public function to return an instance of this protecting wrapper
ProtData::ProtectingWrapper ProtData::getAccess() {
  return ProtectingWrapper(_data, _mutex);
}

// Thread Function:
// access member of given ProtData after given time in a thread-safe manner
void waitAndEditStruct(ProtData* pd, int waitingDur, int val) {
  std::cout << "Start thread and wait\n";

  // wait some time
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(waitingDur));
  // thread-safely access testInt by calling getAccess()
  pd->getAccess().data.testInt = val;
  std::cout << "Edit has been done\n";
}

int main() {
  // Instace of protected data struct
  ProtData protData;
  // Two threads concurrently accessing testInt after 100ms
  std::thread thr1(waitAndEditStruct, &protData, 100, 50);
  std::thread thr2(waitAndEditStruct, &protData, 100, 60);
  thr1.join();
  thr2.join();

  // access and print testInt in a thread-safe manner
  std::cout << "testInt is: " << protData.getAccess().data.testInt << "\n";

  // Intended: Errors while accessing private objects:
  // std::cout << "this won't work: " << protData._data.testInt << "\n";

  // Or:
  // auto wontWork = protData.ProtectingWrapper(/*data obj*/, /*mutex obj*/);
  // std::cout << "won't work as well: " << wontWork.data.testInt << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

## Question

So considering this code I can now access a variable of the struct by `protData.getAccess().data.testInt` from everwhere.

- **But is it truly thread safe?**
- **Would you consider the class as "good code" (performance, readability)?**

I did my best to make the code understandable. If you have any question please write a comment and I will try to explain it more deeply...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you have working code (or at least without any identified issue), then [codereview.se] is better place to post such question.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Ok, sry. Uhm, should I move it or will it produce double posts..?

Comment: @NathanOliver: thx for the comment! With the [attached online compiler](http://www.cpp.sh/2kghx) it even works with  c++11... But even 17 or higher would be ok for me...

Comment: @jakob My mistake, you using a `std::unique_lock` in `ProtectingWrapper`, not a `std::mutex`.  That will work for C++11 and higher.

Comment: Since you've got an answer, I'd say the question can stay here alright. You can still consider posting to Code Review for tips on other things (like readability).

Comment: i am not active at code review, but i heard that they are quite picky about correctness of code posted there, so afaik pointing out mistakes in code isnt what code review is about. I might be wrong though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't thread safe. Consider:

```
ProtData::Data& data_ref = pd->getAccess().data;
```

Now I have a reference to the data and the mutex that was locked when creating a `ProtectingWrapper` is already unlocked, because the temporary wrapper is gone. Even a `const` reference would not fix that because then I could read from that reference while a different thread writes to `data`.

My rule of thumb is: Don't let references (whether `const` or not) leak out of a locked scope.

> Would you consider the class as "good code" (performance, readability)?

This is very opinin-based. Though you should consider that synchronisation isnt soemthing you want to use all over the place, rather only when necessary. In your example you can modify `testInt` and `testBool`, but to do so you need to lock the same mutex twice. If you have a class with many members that require synchronisation then it can get even worse. Consider this, which is simpler and cannot be misused:

```
template <typename T>
struct locked_access {
    private:
        T data;
        std::mutex m;
    public:
        void set(const T& t) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            data = t;
        }
        T get() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            return data;
        }
};
```

However, even this I would probably not use because it does not scale. If I have a type with two `locked_access` members, then I am back at step 1: I want to have detailed control on whether I modify only one of them or both at once. I know it is tempting to write a thread-safe wrapper, but to my experience it just doesn't scale. Rather thread-safety needs to be baked into the design of a type.

PS: You declared `Data` in the private section of `ProtData`, but once an instance of `Data` is accesible via a public method, also the type is accesible. Only the name of the type is private. I should have used `auto` in the line above, but I prefer it that way because it makes more clear what is going on.

Comment: thx! I understand the problem with the reference. I just thought I solved it by setting "Data" to private, but I could still do `auto data_ref = pd->getAccess().data;` right? 
So considering there is no way to prevent that: If I would never create a reference of Data but just use it as proposed `protData.getAccess().data.testInt `. This would not lead to data races, would it?

Comment: @jakob well if you only use it as in your code then it is more or less fine, but it is just too easy to use wrong. I mean having to remember to call it in the right way is almost same effort as having to remember to lock a mutex for each access imho

Comment: @jakob yes for the `auto`. You declared `struct Data` in the private section, but once you return the type from a public method, the type is public. Only its name is not accesible. Actually I had `auto` first, but then replaced it because there was a misunderstanding in a now deleted comment. Now it wont compile, but it is more clear than before, ill add a note

Comment: Aight. I totally get your point. The template you proposed also looks interesting, but if I have many different variables in that struct, how would I access them with a single get/set? In my case I can just use the `protData.getAccess().data.` plus the variable's name, right?...

So would you conclude, that there is no good option to build the thread-safety into the class / a wrapper itself? Should mutexes always be locked where the access gets called?

Comment: `struct foo { int a; bool b; double c; };` and then `locked_access<foo>`. Though that allows only to set all or nothing. Using a mutex and a lock (ie no wrapper) is already the most convenient pattern I am aware of

Comment: There are more downside with my intended usage of the code:
`protData.getAccess().data.testBool = !protData.getAccess().data.testBool;` for example causes the application to hang. I guess because of a deadlock..? I will have to find something else...